# How to update a node or edge property of visjs using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, vis.js

I have a requirement to hide or unhide some nodes and edges depending on some data. I can achieve it by traversing through visjs's data but that will trigger stabilization everytime one hides or unhides (this overwrite existing data).

I found [this example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/data/datasets.html) which adds, updates and removes a node by directly changing `nodes` value by using `add`, `update` & `remove` functions. This dynamically does these operations without stabilizing, but when I try the same thing in AngularJS I encounter the following error

> org_nodes.update is not a function

Snippet taken from source of [this example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/data/datasets.html)

```
function addNode() {
    var newId = (Math.random() * 1e7).toString(32);
    nodes.add({id:newId, label:"I'm new!"});
    nodeIds.push(newId);
}

function changeNode1() {
    var newColor = '#' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255 * 255 * 255)).toString(16);
    nodes.update([{id:1, color:{background:newColor}}]);
}

function removeRandomNode() {
    var randomNodeId = nodeIds[Math.floor(Math.random() * nodeIds.length)];
    nodes.remove({id:randomNodeId});

    var index = nodeIds.indexOf(randomNodeId);
    nodeIds.splice(index,1);
}
```

Check out my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oBjYUURG39swCVLMV4mI?p=preview) which demonstrates this. What is it that I am missing here? Note - I am using [angular-visjs](https://github.com/visjs/angular-visjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be slightly off when calling `update`. Referring to that example, the `update` function requires an argument passed that is a `new vis.DataSet`. You are instead supplying a simple array. We can approach this a couple of ways, but let's make the change when declaring `$scope.data` as such

```
$scope.data = {
    nodes: new vis.DataSet(org_nodes),
    edges: edges
};
```

Now that we have done this, within `$scope.agentClicked` lets modify our call to reference our `vis.DataSet` object

```
$scope.agentClicked = function() {
    $scope.data.nodes.update([ ... ]);
}
```

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zECQ2zQiCcD71oeReEj6?p=preview) - updated demo

Answer (score 1):

Seems not to work anymore in 2022. I worked around this by using `updateClusterNode`:

```
    for (const node of this.data.nodes) {
        this.network.updateClusteredNode(node.id, node);
    }
```

Maybe there is a better way to force an update of nodes data. Let me know ;-) .